# Ubuntu not showing up outside My Computer

Tags: boot

I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 (I think) with my Dell Dimension 4500 running Windows XP, but the only way I can find it is to look in My Computer (C drive).  I looked for an executable file, and since there wasn't one, I tried to open the "bootstrap" file, which the computer couldn't handle.  Then I downloaded EasyFileViewer, only to discover that it requires registration.  What do I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to AskUbuntu!

You cannot run the Ubuntu you just downloaded from within Windows XP. Please read [how to try Ubuntu before you install](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) -- first, [burn it on a DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) or [create a bootable USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), so you become familiar with it and, if you like it, consider following the [step-by-step guide to install it](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows) alongside your Windows.

You can try with the [Long-Term support Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support) or the [most recent version, 13.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest).

Make sure you read and understand everything before you do any changes to your computer, so you do not damage your data or current OS. Look for answers in this website or other places and, if you can't find the right answer, ask!